# CSV File Generation is too slow

Tags: java, performance, csv, servlets

Hi i am using the following code to generate the CSV file using the java servlet but it is taking 40mins to generate a CSV file with no. of rows 3000. is there any other optimized code which can speed up my CSV generation to 1 or 2 mins.
My code is here  :

```
protected void getCSVReportGererated(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{   
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String reportSQL = getReportSQL();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDb","username", "password");
        try{
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(reportSQL);
            ps.execute();
            rs = ps.getResultSet();
            res.setContentType("text/csv");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy-HHMM");
            Date dt = new Date();
            String reportName = "my_report"+sdf.format(dt)+".csv";
            res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; " + "filename=" + reportName);
            ArrayList<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
            rows.add("col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10");
            rows.add("\n");
            String row = null;
            while(rs.next()){
                row = String.format("%04d", Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(1)))+","+String.format("%05d", Integer.parseInt(rs.getString(2)))+","+rs.getString(3)+","+rs.getString(4)+","+rs.getString(5)+","+rs.getString(6)+","+rs.getString(7)+","+rs.getString(8)+","+rs.getString(9)+","+rs.getString(10);
                rows.add(row);
                rows.add("\n");
            }
                Iterator<String> iter = rows.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()){
                    String outputString = (String) iter.next();
                    res.getOutputStream().print(outputString);
                }
                res.getOutputStream().flush();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if (ps != null)
                    ps.close();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
                if(rs != null)
                    rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
}
```

Comment: Try to combine both while loops in one. Maybe evevn without use of 'rows' altogether.

Comment: How much time is spent on retrieving the results? Have you considered skipping to create the `ArrayList<string>` and write to the output stream directly?

Comment: Use multi threading

Comment: Multiple calls to `res` may be slow. You could try building the CSV as one big string and then call `res.getOutputStream().print(oneBigString);` once.

Comment: I agree with @AndreyLebedenko, the use of two loops `while(rs.next())` and `while (iter.hasNext())` going over the same data probably doesn't help your performance.

Comment: The very first thing: performance problems **always** require **measuring**. You almost never solve them by looking at code alone; you always have to understand **what exactly** is going on, where time is spent and where your **real bottlenecks** are.

Comment: I just upvoted Andreys comment on merging loops - but: you still want to break up this code into many more small parts. Ideally, you should iterate lists only once; but you should not never do so many things within one method!

Comment: Why are you calling `execute()` followed by `getResultSet()`, when `executeQuery()` will do both for you, in a simpler, more common way? Why are you using an iterator `while` loop when an enhanced `for` loop will do it for you, in a simpler, more common way? Why are you building a list first, instead of just writing directly to the output stream? Why are you not using try-with-resources for your resource cleanup? Why are you catching `SQLException` and continuing execution as if nothing when wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing way too many things at the same time. There are at least 3 unrelated concerns here:

1. Reading from a Database
2. Converting to CSV
3. Serving that CSV to a HTTP endpoint

I'd develop and test these 3 aspects separately, and identify what takes so long. Your code may not be the most efficient, but it doesn't look like it will take 40 minutes.

Unless your database report is tremendous, in which case it should probably be split into many smaller reports.

Anyway, I'd use an MVC framework (Spring MVC / Spring Boot is a good start) and rewrite your code similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22949362/342852)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print System.currentTimeInMillis() to understand if the time is spent for the db query, for the first while loop or the second while loop.

You could also use only one loop and avoid using the rows list at all printing directly to the output stream.

Comment: +1 for recommending to find the cause of the performance issue. Maybe VisualVM is another option to find the bottleneck.

Comment: I agree in general; but asking for "do profiling" rarely makes up a good answer. So, in that sense this would make a great comment, but maybe not such a great answer.

Comment: You are right, I should comment, but my reputation is still too low. Anyway, if it takes 30 minutes, I suppose the problem is in the ps.execute() line of code.

Comment: I suggest to use System.currentTimeMillis() to measure the time of query execution. If the query execution is too low, the query itself has to be analyzed. Maybe it is a db optimization problem.

Comment: none of your fix worked for me as it is not investing its time on ps.execute() or any other point you suggest.

Comment: my code is holding time on the following line but don't know why
while (iter.hasNext()){
                    String outputString = (String) iter.next();
                    res.getOutputStream().print(outputString);
}

Comment: Try this  substitute code from iterator to flush:      OutputStream stream=res.getOutputStream();   
for (String r: rows){
 stream.print(r);
}    
stream.flush();

Answer (score 0):

Try change like this:

```
protected void getCSVReportGererated(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException{   
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String reportSQL = getReportSQL();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/testDb","username", "password");
        try{
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(reportSQL);
            ps.execute();
            rs = ps.getResultSet();
            res.setContentType("text/csv");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy-HHMM");
            Date dt = new Date();
            String reportName = "my_report"+sdf.format(dt)+".csv";
            res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; " + "filename=" + reportName);
            OutputStream stream=res.getOutputStream();         
            stream.println("col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10");

            String row = null;
            while(rs.next()){
                row = String.format("%04d",rs.getInt(1)))+","+String.format("%05d", rs.getInt(2))+","+rs.getString(3)+","+rs.getString(4)+","+rs.getString(5)+","+rs.getString(6)+","+rs.getString(7)+","+rs.getString(8)+","+rs.getString(9)+","+rs.getString(10);
                stream.println(row);                
            }
            stream.flush();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                if (ps != null)
                    ps.close();
                if (conn != null)
                    conn.close();
                if(rs != null)
                    rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i did it and it impvroves my time to 20 min. Thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. I think you should obtain even better improvement using StringBuffer for the row creation, and optimizing the stream buffer.