# How to convert collection to csv with jackson in java spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, export-to-csv, jackson-databind

I have a problem to convert a java.util.Collection to a csv file with jackson.

In the following code you can see a method to convert the collection to a csv-string.

But i need a method to convert the collection with com.fasterxml.jackson.
The Enum "DownloadType" get the column and headerlines for csv file.

Do you have an idea to fix them?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/csv",
            produces = {"text/csv"},
            consumes = {"application/json"},
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<Object> exportCsv()
{
    ResponseEntity<Object> response = null;
    try
    {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-store, must-revalidate");
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=\"export.csv\"");
            headers.add(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, "0");

            byte[] csvBytes = null;
            byte[] headerBytes = null;
            byte[] lineBytes = null;
            CsvMapper mapper = new 
            Collection<User> users = getUsers()
            headerBytes = DownloadType.USER.getHeaderLine().getBytes("UTF-8");
            lineBytes = mapper.writer(DownloadType.USER.getCsvSchema()).writeValueAsBytes(users);
            if (headerBytes != null && lineBytes != null)
            {
                csvBytes = new byte[headerBytes.length + lineBytes.length];
                System.arraycopy(headerBytes, 0, csvBytes, 0, headerBytes.length);
                System.arraycopy(lineBytes, 0, csvBytes, headerBytes.length, lineBytes.length);
            }
            response = new ResponseEntity<>(csvBytes, headers, HttpStatus.OK);


    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return response;
}
```

Comment: What is the exact issue you're facing with this code? Is it that you can't use CsvMapper like you have it or is there an error?

Comment: The problem is, that i must not use the byte arrays. I must use the jackson libary to convert the collection to csv-file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try something like this. By writing the data directly to the servlet response the string will get returned directly back to the client as is without formatting or post-processing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/csv",
            produces = {"text/csv"},
            consumes = {"application/json"},
            method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void exportCsv(HttpServletResponse response)
{
    ...
    String headerString = DownloadType.USER.getHeaderLine()
    String data = mapper.writer(DownloadType.USER.getCsvSchema()).writeValueAsString(users);
response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=utf-8");
    response.getWriter().print(headerString);
    response.getWriter().print(data);
```

Adapted from:
[How to Return CSV Data in Browser From Spring Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947751/how-to-return-csv-data-in-browser-from-spring-controller)

Comment: Thank if i used the last 2 lines of your code, than i got a correct csv-string. This is better than my version of code.