# RestAPI in java return Json and CSR file

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-restcontroller, csr

I have a @RestController, which returns `ResponseEntity<Object>` and my response is of JSON, and the response class name is EmployeeDetail.

Now I need to return a CSR file, along with the Json employeeDetail and the crucial part is that the Postman should be able to identify the CSR file and Postman should be able to download the CSR.

Can you please suggest me how to implement this.

I have various query for its implementation :

1. In class EmployeeDetail, what should be the dataType of the field, which will store the CSR file?
2. How I can return the response with CSR file and EmployeeDetail as name, id, password, etc?
3. How the postman will identify that the received JSON also contains a CSR file and it should download it?

Comment: Did you see this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947751/how-to-return-csv-data-in-browser-from-spring-controller

Comment: @MukeshKeshu thank you for the response, but the file I am looking for is CSR, not CSV. apart from that, in the first part I don't understand that in what dataType I can store the CSR into java class EmployeeDetail.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure, by 'CSR file' you are referring to certificate signing request file?
If that's the case - it means that you can have it in BASE64 form (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request#Example).

If that's the case - you can add a String field to the EmployeeDetail class and add the BASE64 CSR string, 
 BUT make sure to add '\n' (newline) after `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` 
 and before `-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----` .

All other chars can be one long line.

Later on the client you can write this string to a file and have the CSR file.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @user514949  for the '\n' point and yes we can do client-side development, but here is no frontend, this is purely configuration API and the thing is that It should be testable in postman also right, so suppose I set the CSR value in a string and then give a response, then the postman will not be able to understand that it is a CSR value, Is there any way that postman will be able to recognize it and I can down the CSR file through the postman ?

Comment: I don't now if Postman can understand that this is a file, I did not work it for automatic testing
.
When returning a response you can return a single object; by returning a the String of the CSR you can get the CSR value and manipulate it as you wish, e.g. take the string and generate a certificate for the employee.

Comment: As alternative you can have the CSR filed in the EmployeeDetail be a URL for downloading the CSR file (expose it as a resource on your webserver)